# How to insert data to nested document in elasticsearch recursively using RestHighLevelClient using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, insert, resthighlevelclient

I have created below index. I want to insert nested data to "companyaddress" recursively using RestHighLevelClient in Spring Boot. Means I want to insert data into companyaddress for every request time.

```
 "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "company_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "company_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "likely_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer" : "standard"
        },
        "companyaddress" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "address3" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "likely_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer" : "standard"
            },
            "main_phone1" : {
              "type" : "long"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide an example of the desired outcome? For more tips see [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: find sample outcome.

"_source" : {
          "company_id" : "3",
          "company_name" : "DEFG",
          "companyaddress" : [
            {
              "address3" : "smp1",
              "main_phone1" : "1"
            },
            {
              "address3" : "chtp2",
              "main_phone1" : "2"
            },
            {
              "address3" : "gmd",
              "main_phone1" : "3"
            },
            {
              "address3" : "tste",
              "main_phone1" : "4"
            }
          ]
        }